# How to remove all the elements from recyclerview and add new elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

It may sound like a simple thing but it's been a pain in the neck from last 3 days . I tried all the possible ways to remove data like removing `adapter data`,removing `recyclerview elements` but none of them are working . Can anyone please help me fix this issue ?

Code:

```
                       //Adapter Setting
                            adapteru=new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);


                    //Data Clearing Code
                    timelineDataList.clear();
                    posts_rView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    posts_rView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just recreate and reatach your adapter. the performance difference between doing this and clearing the dataset is absolutely ignorable, the code mess it creates is a lot smaller.

Ideally you should have a

```
void showData(List<TimeLineData> timelineDataList){
    adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(timelineDataList);
    yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //assumed you attached your layout manager earlier
}
```

call it with your data or Collections.emptyList() as an argument

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution

Answer (score 1):

It would be on the adapter.  You'd remove all the data in the adapter, such that getItemCount returns 0 (how you do that is specific to your adapter).  Then call notifyDataSetChanged.  You would NOT touch the recycled views or the recycleview directly.

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your answer but as you can see I'm clearing the datalist and doing the notifyDataSetChanged . Could you please tell what else do i need to do?

Comment: I see you clearing some list.  Without knowing your adapter, where its getting its data from, and how it may have copied or cached things, I have no idea if that actually has any effect.  But the two steps I mentioned are all you need to do.

Comment: sir you can check the updated question there I've mentioned how am i setting data to adapter